# Count digits in a given number using recursion

Tags: python, python-2.x, recursion

Here is my code that finds the number of digits in a given integer (either positive or negative). The code works and results in expected output.

```
'''
Program that returns number of digits in a given integer (either positive or negative)
'''
def ndigits(x):
    # Assume for the input 0 the output is 0
    if(x == 0):
        return 0
    if(abs(x) / 10 == 0):
        return 1
    else:
        return 1 + ndigits(x / 10)
```

Comment: `def ndigits(x): return sum(int(i) for i in str(x))` Here are a few other solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939953/sum-the-digits-of-a-number-python.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: He is not interested in the sum of the digits only in the number of digits. But the solutions can be adapted to this difference.

Comment: @MrSmith42 `def ndigits(x): return 1 + int(log(x, 10)` Something I am still missing?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: The link to the 'few other solutions' is a link to where the sum of the digits is calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pro:

- code is clean and easy to understand

con:

- a recursive solution may not be optimized to a loop by your interpreter so there might be a lot of memory (stack) waste because of the recursion overhead. (So you could implement it as a loop instead of a recursion)
- You do not need the `if(abs(x) / 10 == 0)` branch. So to simplify your code you could remove it.

**Simplified recursive code:**

```
def ndigits(x):
    # Assume for the input 0 the output is 0
    if(x == 0):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + ndigits(abs(x) / 10)
```

**Simplified tail-recursive code:**
end-recursive methods are likely to be detected by the interpreter and transformed to a loop. So this code might be faster and may nor waste memory.
For more information see wikipedia [Tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)

```
def ndigits(x):
    return ndigits_(0, abs(x))

def ndigits_(s,x):
    if(x == 0):
        return s
    else:
        return ndigits(s+1, x / 10)
```

Comment: The python interpreter doesn't do that sort of optimization period.  There is some sort of work going on in that area, but that is the case right now.

Comment: @TheBlackCat: tail recursion is a very common optimization, so we can expect it also from the python interpreter in the near future. But good to know that it is not the case yet.

Comment: Not going to happen.  Guido has explicitly rejected adding tail recursion to Python.